# Sql: How to get the total monthly income and expenses for a certain year

Tags: sql, sqlite

this is table record:

```
id    date         type       amount
1     2020-08-03   income     88
2     2020-09-11   spending   -120
3     2020-09-16   income     200
4     2020-11-05   income     95
5     2020-11-30   spending   35
```

How to get monthly statistics from year?

for example :

```
{
   "2021-11": {income: 500, spending: -800}
   "2021-10": {income: 200, spending: -500}
   "2021-09": {income: 800, spending: -300}
   "2021-08": {income: 900, spending: -200}
}
```

ps: Sqlite

Comment: Don't tag spam; when tagging an RDBMS just tag the one you are **really** using, not 3 completely different ones.

Comment: Column date data type?

Comment: Does the expected result really match the sample data?!?

Comment: @Larnu, it wasn't OP who added all those tags...

Comment: You're right, I hadn't noticed that @jarlh . I'm too used to low rep users tag spamming; not someone who should know better adding tag spam in an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use case statement in sum group function to determine if it is an income or a spending line

```
select strftime('%Y-%m', date_col),
       sum(case when type = 'income' then amount else 0 end) income,
       sum(case when type = 'spending' then amount else 0 end) spending
  from test_table
 group by strftime('%Y-%m', date_col);
```

Comment: Hi @jarlh. There was an "sqlite" tag when I wrote this answer

Comment: @jarth,  that's weird. I've updated the answer

Comment: Someone (not OP) messed up the tags. I've put the sqlite tag back.